# Avoid to insert duplication of custom field value on submit?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

My Custom Field(A checkbox with 1 value if checked)

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="mytheme_checkbox_value" value="1" <?php checked($mytheme_checkbox_value, 1); ?> /><?php esc_attr_e('Make It Public', 'mytheme'); ?></label>
```

See admin side custom input field(checkbox) and custom fields records in "wp_postmeta" table in phpmyadmin. And see duplicated records at admin record list page, status column have public value is a custom field value showing in records at admin page.

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: You have to check the field before insert.

Comment: use `update_post_meta()` method instead `add_post_meta()`